# CI not working on mamp

Tags: php, macos, codeigniter, mamp

I have installed Codeigniter project on my mac MAMP. only the default index (login) page is working, rest after redirecting i get :

**Not Found
The requested URL /usc/login/check was not found on this server.**

Comment: Post your `.htaccess`. What does the URL your accessing the site look like for the `/usc/login/check` page?

Comment: .htaccess is not visible in mac, is there any other option

Comment: Drag your entire CI-install to a code editor such as Textmate, `.htaccess` should be visible in the project drawer.

Comment: Also make sure you have apache `rewrite module` enabled for `.htaccess` to work properly.